# Changing random words from strings with php

Tags: php

I looking for content spining function who can randomly change choosed on a text.

Ex:

I have this text :

```
$text = 'This is my nice text';
```

or this text :

```
$text = 'That is my beautiful text';
```

And only one rule like this :

```
$alternative '{(this|here|that)(nice|beautiful|cute)}';
```

Any idea or way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, I've an idea - but what is your first approach?

Answer (score 1):

I quickly threw something together like this:

```
    $string = "This is my nice text";

    $array = array("nice", "beautiful", "cute");

    $rand = $array[rand(0, 2)];

    echo str_replace("nice", $rand, $string);
```

I don't know how well this would work. If you wanted one of each then I guess you could run it through a `foreach` instead.

However, if you wanted this with different options you'd have to do a multidimensional array.

```
$string = "This is my nice text";

$array = array(array("nice", "beautiful", "cute"), array("this", "here", "that"));

$choice_one = $array[1][rand(0,2)];
$choice_two = $array[0][rand(0,2)];

echo str_replace(array("This", "nice"), array($choice_one, $choice_two), $string);
```

Here is it working with multiple words in a single string.

Not very efficient though...

Comment: This approach looks good - but you should explode `$string` too and check every single word if it appears in `$array`. So it's more organic. But first I'd wait for a first approach by the guy that asked this question before do the whole work for him ;)

Comment: @Jurik Thanks for your feedback! :) 

It's only because I'm looking to do the same thing so it gave me a reason to work on it. 

Do you know why I'd possibly get the down vote? :/

Comment: I've no idea - cuz your solution mixed up with @Snowburnt solution is a very good solution. I give you an up ;) - and I'd still put the blown up `$string` into a `foreach loop` and check if it's in one of the arrays - and then replace it with a random word from this array.

Comment: @Jurik Thanks! :) And OK I'm not very good at PHP but I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

you could use explode to pull it into an array:

```
$textArray = explode(" ", $text);
```

The rule is a little different, brute force I'd think you'd want to take out the curly brackets, break it up into a "rule array" (use sub string functions to remove curly brackets, create the first level rule arrays based on parenthesis and then explode on pipes) so you'd have an array that looked something like this:

```
rule[0][0]->"this"
rule[0][1]->"here"
rule[0][2]->"that"
rule[1][0]->"nice"
rule[1][1]->"beautiful"
rule[1][2]->"cute"
```

based on your input you could do this:

```
$alternative = substr_replace($alternative, "{(", 0);
$alternative = substr_replace($alternative, ")}", 0);
$rule=explode(")(",$alternative);
for ($i=0; $i<$rule.count(); i++){
    $rule[i]=explode("|",$rule[i]);
}
```

then have a triple nested for loop that goes through the textarray checking based on every value of the rule array.  on a match you replace it with a random value from the same level of the rule array and then break out of that level of the for loop so it doesn't validate again. like this:

```
foreach ($textArray as $i){
    for($x=0; $x<$rule.count(); $x++){
        for($y=0;$y<$rule[x].count(); $y++) {
            if ($i == $rule[$x][$y]) {
               $z=$y+1;
               if ($z == $rule[x].count()) {$z=0;}
               $i = $rule[$x][$z];
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mixup your solution with @BeatAlex 's ones , then you got it ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try : *PHP Sentence Randomizer*

Github : https://github.com/Marko-M/php-sentence-randomizer/

More infos : http://www.techytalk.info/php-random-sentence-spinning-function/